# How can I extend a node_module file that module.exports just a few variables, but is used throughout the entire module? (w/ example)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm using a node module whose file structure is imaged below.

Within the file `node_core_ctx.js` it has the following code:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

let sessions = new Map();
let publishers = new Map();
let idlePlayers = new Set();
let nodeEvent = new EventEmitter();
let stat = {
  inbytes: 0,
  outbytes: 0,
  accepted: 0
};

module.exports = { sessions, publishers, idlePlayers, nodeEvent, stat };
```

and this code is imported and used throughout this entire project. I would like to extend this file and a couple of the classes within the other files inside of the project I'm working on, but if I extend this file then it's not going to work because it's still being imported locally within the node module. What's the best way to extend this file so it's still gets read but it also has the new variables that I want to add to it?

My thoughts are that I should just create a new file and use that in the extended objects, but not sure if I will run into issues going that route at some point. What's the best way to do this?

---

[image]

Comment: Try asking questions with the phrasing "how can I..." rather than "what's the best way to..."  The first way sets out a clearly defined objective and requirements, the second one is too open ended and will tend to draw opinions and low quality answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new module that does a `require()` of the existing module, adds a few new properties to it and then exports all of it.  Then, anyone who wants the extended module can just `require()` in your new module and they will get both the originals and the extensions.

```
// node_core_ctx_extended.js

// get original exports
let data = require('node_core_ctx.js');

// add some new properties to it
data.someNewProperty1 = someNewValue1;    
data.someNewProperty2 = someNewValue2;

// export the combined object
module.exports = data;
```

Then, anywhere you want to use the extended version:

```
const core_extended = require('node_core_ctx_extended.js');
```

Comment: For a good example of this strategy check out Express.js which extends node's built-in `http.Server` class without editing the files implementing `http.Server`. Express's `app` class is basically node's `http.Server` with extra features like a middleware layer

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll give this a shot. What about extending a class just to rename a single variable within one of the methods? I just recreated the method which I'm sure is the only way, but just a shot in the dark just in case there's a method for doing this I'm not aware of.

Comment: @BlakeBell - I don't understand what you mean by "rename a single variable within one of the methods".  You would have to show the specific code and describe what you're trying to accomplish (perhaps in a new question).  It shouldn't concern you what variable names are used inside of methods as those would be in a private scope and not accessible outside the method anyway.